# Pure.CSS menu heading and menu list on same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yui-pure-css

I am using the Pure.css (purecss.io) framework to layout a website. I am using a horizontal menu along the top of the screen. I can't work out how to position menu items to be on the same (first) row as the menu heading. ie in HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed">
        <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="">My Website</a>
        <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Tour</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the standard pure.css file and I suspect the issue is something to do with either using a ul tag or because the default pure layout is a vertical menu underneath the menu heading. Has anyone managed to position heading and list on the same line (eg as per a bootstrap header)?

Comment: What do you mean? If I run that code everything appears to be on one straight line.

Comment: When the pure.css is used the heading and menu items are on separate lines. The answer below by Trix fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `li`s be in one line, next to each other, you may use floats:

```
.pure-menu-list{ list-style: none; }
.pure-menu-list li{ float: left; }
```

So:

```css
.pure-menu-heading{ float: left; }
.pure-menu-list{ float: left;list-style: none; margin: 0; }
.pure-menu-list li{ float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed">
        <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="">My Website</a>
        <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Tour</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: @DonSyme "The whole point of Pure CSS is to avoid flow-breaking floats. Not saying your finding is not correct, but the solution should be non-floating." See https://github.com/yahoo/pure/issues/499#issuecomment-108750871